# Étymologie du mot « Reel » ou sens de ce terme utilisé en musique Traditionnel Québécoise

Tags: expressions, étymologie, québec

Au Québec, nous avons le mot **reel** se prononçant « *rille* », « *reel* » ou « *reill* » .
 [Google nous le traduit en Bobine, Moulinet, etc.](https://translate.google.com/#en/fr/reel)... Ce n'est donc pas une traduction directe car il n'y a aucun lien apparent. En y repensant, c'est vrai qu'en allant à la pêche, j'ai souvent entendu dire :

> « Oublie pas de « *reeler* », il y a une branche à cet endroit ».
>
> **Dans cet exemple, on comprend vite que cela à un lien avec le moulinet
>   et la ligne. Donc, de ramener la ligne.**

Mais que veut dire exactement **reel**, utilisé dans la musique traditionnelle ?

Je sais qu'il a sensiblement la même signification que [rigodon](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rigodon) mais d'où provient-il et que veut-il dire exactement?

D'ailleurs, nous disons *rigodon* ou *reel* mais à quoi associons-nous cela exactement? Est-ce plutôt la danse elle-même, les chants et la musique ou bien les deux?

Comment: Selon le Wiktionnaire, *reel* serait une ronde écossaise, une ronde étant ceci: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ronde#/media/File:BookOfNurseryRhymes_p99.jpg

Commentaire impertinent: Je n'ai jamais entendu parler de ce mot.

Comment: Au Québec, c'est dans la musique « Trad » : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jusqu'aux_p'tites_heures, Piste #2. C'est une exemple, mais ça arrive quelque fois dans les chansons de ce genre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[reel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reel) vient de l'anglais :

> **Etymology**
>
> From Middle English ***reel***, *reele*, from Old English *rēol*, *hrēol*. Cognate with Icelandic *ræl*, *hræl*.

Il ne faut donc pas chercher une étymologie latine et c'est pour cela que mes liens seront tous en anglais.

---

#### 1

En lisant l'article de [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reel_%28dance%29), on tombe sur :

> The earliest reference was in a witchcraft trial of 1590, where the accused was reported to have « daunced this reill or short dance ».

On peut imaginer une sorte de transe pour lancer une malédiction ...

---

#### 2

Et en lisant la [liste Wikipedia des sens de *reel*](http://Reel,%20a%20complex%20bird%20vocalization%20consisting%20of%20several%20short%20elements%20which%20are%20repeated%20regularly.%20It%20is%20a%20territorial%20song%20when%20used%20by%20fairy-wrens%20of%20the%20family%20Maluridae), on peut lire en dernière position :

> Reel, a complex bird vocalization consisting of several short elements which are repeated regularly. It is a territorial song when used by fairy-wrens of the family *Maluridae*

Il s'agit donc ici d'un chant d'oiseau constituté de plusieurs petites parties qui se répètent régulièrement.

---

#### Conclusion

Les deux explications sur le sens musical de *reel* se recoupent, il s'agit de motifs musicaux qui se répètent, **en boucle** (*on rejoint ici le sens de bobine*).

Il s'agit donc plutôt de la *mélodie* que des pas de danse en eux-mêmes.

Comment: Donc, un mot français purement Québécois, ayant comme provenance un mot anglais, qui lui, provient d'un mot Irlandais? C'est tout de même cocasse.

Comment: @SimonDugré Ce n'est pas un mot français purement Québécois, c'est un anglicisme venant du Québec. Et cela vient de l'Islandais, pas de l'Irlandais.

Comment: Oh, pardon. Merci. Par purement Québécois je voulais dire qu'ailleurs qu'au Québec, ce mot n'est pas utilisé (France, Belgique, etc.)

Comment: @SimonDugré Effectivement, je ne le connais pas ;)

Answer (score 3):

Amateur de danses historiques et de costume, j'ai déjà eu l'occasion de danser ces morceaux traditionnels : il s'agit de danses collectives, comme souvent à l'époque baroque, dans lesquelles les couples répètent tour à tour une figure et vont se placer à l'autre extrémité de l'alignement (en passant sous les bras en arceaux par exemple). 
Cela explique la notion de boucle ou d'enroulement. Bien que le mot anglais n'y soit pas rattaché (selon les sources comme l'O.E.D.), on ne peut manquer de relever la proximité avec le mot « roue » et surtout avec le « rouet » de filature de la laine.